# Is it possible to reset asp_membership provider (hashed) pwd directly from db?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

**Q:**  Is it possible to reset a hashed password directly within the asp_membership provider db?

Comment: How do you mean directly within the provider db? Actually with your own sql or just in sql management studio or through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there should be a stored-procedure named `aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword` which will do just this.